# Unity Remote Config 3.X scriptting correctly for remotly configs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Some days ago I meet a new problem with my game in Unity and this problem is about Remote Config. For some time I wanted to implement a little system with what I want to make some change about values and some things in my game remotly. Now my little problem is this: On internet or on most sites I see old configuration in scripts with RemoteConfig (principal thing (i don't know how I can say) in scripting with what you can make script and with what you can make connection between game and Unity Servers with online datas), and now with versions: 3.X for remote config The struct of file is complete different (with different services) and I understood very broadly how it works but with my attempts all is okey-sh (ok but maybe not) but I have sometimes some errors about my scripts with this component, Remote Config. I.E. I have in my script an warnings about authentification and core service.
Now bellow I put my script and Unity sample to see an error and I want to help me with solution for my problem to make a good script for my game to make changes remotly
P.S.: I want make a little note. I am logged in Unity with my account and connection between Unity and Unity servers is ok i guess because datas about online datas is correct (strings and boools) and enviroment id is the same with enviroment Id in dashboard in browser.
P.S.2: I have all time internet connection for all the same features in unity

Help me please, thx.

My script:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Services.RemoteConfig;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class RemoteConfigGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public struct userAttributes { }
    public struct appAttributes { }


    public bool existUpdate;
    public bool existMaintainance;
    [SerializeField] GameManager gameManager;
    [HideInInspector] string cloudVersion;

    async Task InitializeRemoteConfigAsync()
    {
        // initialize handlers for unity game services
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();

        // remote config requires authentication for managing environment information
        if (!AuthenticationService.Instance.IsSignedIn)
        {
            await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
        }
    }

      public void Awake()
      {
            RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchCompleted += ApplyRemoteSettings;
            RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());
      }

    void ApplyRemoteSettings(ConfigResponse configResponse)
    {

        switch (configResponse.requestOrigin)
        {
            case ConfigOrigin.Default:
                Debug.Log("Default values will be returned");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Cached:
                Debug.Log("Cached values loaded");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Remote:
                Debug.Log("Remote Values changed");
                Debug.Log("RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig fetched: " + RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig.config.ToString());
                break;
        }
        existMaintainance = RemoteSettings.GetBool("isMaintainance");
        existUpdate = RemoteSettings.GetBool("isUpdate");
        cloudVersion = RemoteSettings.GetString("publishVersion");

    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (existUpdate && !existMaintainance)
        {
            if (gameManager.wasUpdatePannel == false && gameManager.manuPannel.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                if ((cloudVersion != gameManager.versionString) && gameManager.wasLoaded == true)
                {
                    gameManager.updatePannel.SetActive(true);
                    gameManager.manuPannel.SetActive(false);
                    gameManager.versionForUpToDate = cloudVersion;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gameManager.updatePannel.SetActive(false);
                gameManager.manuPannel.SetActive(true);
            }


        }
        else if ((existUpdate && existMaintainance) || (!existUpdate && existMaintainance) )
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Maintainance");
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchCompleted -= ApplyRemoteSettings;

    }

}
```

Unity Sample:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// This sample example C# file can be used to quickly utilise usage of Remote Config APIs
// For more comprehensive code integration, visit https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.remote-config@latest
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Services.RemoteConfig;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;


public class ExampleSample : MonoBehaviour
{

    public struct userAttributes {}
    public struct appAttributes {}

    async Task InitializeRemoteConfigAsync()
    {
            // initialize handlers for unity game services
            await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();

            // options can be passed in the initializer, e.g if you want to set analytics-user-id use two lines from below:
            // var options = new InitializationOptions().SetOption("com.unity.services.core.analytics-user-id", "my-user-id-123");
            // await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(options);

            // remote config requires authentication for managing environment information
            if (!AuthenticationService.Instance.IsSignedIn)
            {
                await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
            }
    }

    async Task Start()
    {
        // initialize Unity's authentication and core services, however check for internet connection
        // in order to fail gracefully without throwing exception if connection does not exist
        if (Utilities.CheckForInternetConnection())
        {
            await InitializeRemoteConfigAsync();
        }

        RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchCompleted += ApplyRemoteSettings;
        RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());

        // -- Example on how to fetch configuration settings using filter attributes:
        // var fAttributes = new filterAttributes();
        // fAttributes.key = new string[] { "sword","cannon" };
        // RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes(), fAttributes);

        // -- Example on how to fetch configuration settings if you have dedicated configType:
        // var configType = "specialConfigType";
        // RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(configType, new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());
        // -- Configuration can be fetched with both configType and fAttributes passed
        // RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(configType, new userAttributes(), new appAttributes(), fAttributes);

        // -- All examples from above will also work asynchronously, returning Task<RuntimeConfig>
        // await RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigsAsync(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());
        // await RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigsAsync(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes(), fAttributes);
        // await RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigsAsync(configType, new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());
        // await RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigsAsync(configType, new userAttributes(), new appAttributes(), fAttributes);
    }

    void ApplyRemoteSettings(ConfigResponse configResponse)
    {

        switch (configResponse.requestOrigin)
        {
            case ConfigOrigin.Default:
                Debug.Log("Default values will be returned");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Cached:
                Debug.Log("Cached values loaded");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Remote:
                Debug.Log("Remote Values changed");
                Debug.Log("RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig fetched: " + RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig.config.ToString());
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

With my code I have 2 warnings and i want to fix

```
Core Service not initialized.
Request might result in empty or incomplete response
Please refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.remote-config@3.0/manual/CodeIntegration.html
```

and

```
Auth Service not initialized.
Request might result in empty or incomplete response
Please refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.remote-config@3.0/manual/CodeIntegration.html
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation at the html file in the error messages?   Make sure you read the two blue links in the first paragraph.

Comment: Yes, I read, but on skipped

Comment: You first error indicates the the Core Service was not initialized.  See : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.services.core@1.1/manual/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is happening because of the `Update()`. Add an extra `bool` in the `Update` method which will be check if services are initialized or not. Or you can try the below code.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Services.RemoteConfig;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class RemoteConfigGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public struct userAttributes { }
    public struct appAttributes { }


    public bool existUpdate;
    public bool existMaintainance;
    private bool isInitialized;

    [SerializeField] GameManager gameManager;
    [HideInInspector] string cloudVersion;

    async Task InitializeRemoteConfigAsync()
    {
        // initialize handlers for unity game services
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();

        // remote config requires authentication for managing environment information
        if (!AuthenticationService.Instance.IsSignedIn)
        {
            await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
        }
        
        isInitialized = true;
    }

      public void Awake()
      {
            RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchCompleted += ApplyRemoteSettings;
            RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchConfigs(new userAttributes(), new appAttributes());
      }

    void ApplyRemoteSettings(ConfigResponse configResponse)
    {

        switch (configResponse.requestOrigin)
        {
            case ConfigOrigin.Default:
                Debug.Log("Default values will be returned");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Cached:
                Debug.Log("Cached values loaded");
                break;
            case ConfigOrigin.Remote:
                Debug.Log("Remote Values changed");
                Debug.Log("RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig fetched: " + RemoteConfigService.Instance.appConfig.config.ToString());
                break;
        }
        existMaintainance = RemoteSettings.GetBool("isMaintainance");
        existUpdate = RemoteSettings.GetBool("isUpdate");
        cloudVersion = RemoteSettings.GetString("publishVersion");

    }



    void Update()
    {
        if(!isInitialized) return;

        if (existUpdate && !existMaintainance)
        {
            if (gameManager.wasUpdatePannel == false && gameManager.manuPannel.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                if ((cloudVersion != gameManager.versionString) && gameManager.wasLoaded == true)
                {
                    gameManager.updatePannel.SetActive(true);
                    gameManager.manuPannel.SetActive(false);
                    gameManager.versionForUpToDate = cloudVersion;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gameManager.updatePannel.SetActive(false);
                gameManager.manuPannel.SetActive(true);
            }


        }
        else if ((existUpdate && existMaintainance) || (!existUpdate && existMaintainance) )
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Maintainance");
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        RemoteConfigService.Instance.FetchCompleted -= ApplyRemoteSettings;

    }
}
```